# How to organize a project's Helm chart structure

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a project composed of multiple services that share some things in common (e.g., DB endpoints). The project's repo structure keeps the code and configuration of each service independent of the others. I'm using Helm to deploy the project's services and common infrastructure to Kuberentes. I've settled on an approach for organizing the various Helm charts, but I'm not sure if it's in keeping with Helm best practices.

My approach is to have a project level helm chart and include each service's helm chart within each service's directory structure. E.g.,

```
project-+
        |-helm
        |-svc-1-+
                |-helm
        |-svc-2-+
                |-helm
        ...
```

Is this a common/accepted approach? Is there a better approach?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but here's a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099945/designing-helm-charts-for-microservices-based-application?rq=1

Comment: And another - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545829/helm-managing-a-collection-of-services?rq=1